# How to achieve asp.net form authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a web app with few web forms and I’m removed form authentication in web.config file.

May I know is it safe to use session variable to store logged user data ?

Ex: session(“loggeduser”) = “John”
session(“loggeduserID”) = “123”

**What I have tried:**

Up on user login with login page , I store userID and user name as session(“loggeduserID”) = “123”, then on each I’m checking if session(“loggeduserID”) is having a value. It will redirect to login page if there is no value .

Also session having a userID , it will check SQL database to check if there is an entry in database for the specific user for the specific form name .

Currently everything works smooth and ok , ***is it safe to use user authentication to each form with the value stored in session(“x”) ?***

If not , what is the best way to achieve the same ? I need to specify user role for each web forms on my website

Comment: Why not use [Forms Authentication](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308157/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp-net-applicatio)?

Comment: sir, i have tried forms authentication today and everything set up as per your link. now on the default page i need to retrieve data from SQL based on "logged in user". eg: i have a query as follows **select emailID from users where username = "X"** . how can i retrieve the logged username so that i can set it to **X**

Comment: Please, do some research. This question would have been resolve by simply searching the internet using the title of your question. I suspect that with a little searching you'll be able to find the answer to your new question. If not, try some things out, do some more research, try some other things out, and then if nothing works, ask a new question with the attempts you've made and the research you've done. Please read [ask] for more tips on how to ask questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  i have tried with session value and check if it matches my database roles on each page, everything works fine and my question is "is it possible for client side user to modify session values ? if they modify they can present to be some other user"